# Understand the build number in Android

Tags: android, android-build

I recently bought a new android phone from market. I am having difficulty in understanding the build code of my phone. My build code is

> TBW591331_8376_V3018

I searched the net but I haven't found any build number starting with TBW. Can anyone tell me what it mean and also how to change the build number.

Answer (score 1):

you should not change the build number, it must be unique number, but you can if your device is rooted and installed custom rom that has it own build number.

Comment: Can you tell me what it means by build starting with TBW

Answer (score 1):

I see from other forum :

**First letter** = release family, e.g. F is Froyo
**Second letter** = branch code that allows Google to identify the exact code branch that the build was made from, and R is by convention the primary release branch
**Third letter and the two numbers** = date code. The letter counts quarters, with A being Q1 2009. Therefore, F is Q2 2010. The two digits count days within the quarter, so F85 is June 24 2010.
**Last letter** = individual versions related to the same date code, sequentially starting with A; A is actually implicit and usually omitted for brevity.

[link source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/help-understand-android-build-t1655863)